# How to get the values of the select option for the show modal?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a select option like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IQ1m.png):

```html
<form action="#" class="modal-content">
    <select class="form-select" id="value" name="value">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="1">Driver2</option>
        <option value="2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="2">Driver1</option>
        <option value="3" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="3">Driver3</option>
        <option value="4" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="4">Create date</option>
    </select>
...
```

I want to get the values of the select option for the show modal.

For example, when I select the below option, I want to show the modal of bootstrap 5 like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxkii.png).:

```html
<option value="2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#valueModal" data-id="2">Driver1</option>
```

I also have a Bootstrap modal window:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="valueModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="valueModal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <form action="#" class="modal-content">
            <input value="" name="option_id" type="hidden">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="valueModal">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Multi Forms -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to show the Bootstrap modal if the value `value` is selected.

I have tried doing this:

```js
<script>
    $("#value").bind("change", function () {
        $('#valueModal').modal('show')(this.value === 'option_id');
    }).change();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the child `option` tags by using `selectElement.options` and can access them by index like an array.

```
sel.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  let selectedOption = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
  console.log(selectedOption); // get the element
  console.log(selectedOption.value); //get the value attribute
  console.log(selectedOption.innerText); // get the inner text
});
```

```js
const sel = document.getElementById("select");


sel.addEventListener("change",()=>{
  let selectedOption = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex];
  console.log(selectedOption); // get the element
  console.log(selectedOption.value); //get the value attribute
  console.log(selectedOption.innerText); // get the inner text
});
```

```html
<select id='select'>
<option value='1'>One</option>
<option value='2'>Two</option>
<option value='3'>Three</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How to get `Two` and `value` of option?

Comment: @MahmoudKhoravi I've edited my answer. Once you have the element you can get all of that information easily :D See if that helps